# Creating a custom windows base container image

Tags: windows, containers, virtualization

Pretty much as the title states, as this information seems to be unknown by everybody on the internet??? How can I create my own windows base image to be used with the hcs api. (NOT windows server core / nano + added layers). I am trying to create a custom **Base image** from scratch. General information about the anatomy of a container image would also be helpful.